# Execute javascript onclick button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are thousand of topics about this, but I haven't found anyone with same problem. I have tryed many example but I don't know what I'm wrong. I have created this example that calls data from db and fills one of two selections in this html page. I have two functions, one executed correctly when I charge page, but I should want execute the second when I click on button. Well, if I charge both functions on load using body tag, it works properly, while if I charge the first on load and I try to call the second by onclick event it doesn't works. Can someone helps me? Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function getServ() {
var url = "all_wom.php";
var sel = document.getElementById('service1');
var obj;
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
//  ajax
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
  obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
  for ( i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

   var opt = document.createElement('option');
   opt.innerHTML = obj[i].Descrizione; 
   opt.value = obj[i].ID;
   sel.appendChild(opt);
  }
 }

}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

function getCol() {
var url = "all_col.php";
var sel = document.getElementById('service2');

var obj;
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

  for ( i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

   var opt = document.createElement('option');
   opt.innerHTML = obj[i].Nome; 
   opt.value = obj[i].ID;
   sel.appendChild(opt);
  }
 }

 }
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
<body onload=getCol();>
 <form name="form" >

 <br />
 <br />
 <label>First Select</label><select id="service1"  ></select>
 <br />
 <br />
 <br />
 <br />
 <label>Servizi </label><select id="service2" ></select>
 <br />
 <br />

 <input type="submit" align="center" onClick=getServ(); value="service1" />
 <input type="submit" align="center" value="service2" />
 <br />
 <br />
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I can't see any code there which goes anywhere near a click event. Why should it do anything on click?

Comment: I have just edited code. Trying many times and many examples i had deleted onclick event on button. I disagree your -1, sorry.

Comment: You might want to address the errors that would be picked up if you [used a validator](https://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: Maybe @Quentin, but if i charge it onload event it works. So I think to use a new method as linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click event is attached to a submit button.

When you click the button you:

1. Trigger the Ajax request
2. Submit the form
3. Leave the page
4. Destroy the JavaScript environment the Ajax request is running in (so there is nowhere for the Ajax respond handler to run now)
5. Load a new page

If you want the Ajax to work, you need to prevent the default behaviour of the submit button.

Using legacy intrinsic event attributes in the way you are, you would `return false;` from the onclick attribute. You should switch to [modern event binding techniques](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) through.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin, I supposed what you have suggested, but I didn't know how to solve. I will try the addeventlistener wich is explained in link you have indicated.